# Is my visa valid and can I use it to travel?

Tags: visas

I sent a mail to UKVI stating that I wanted to withdraw my visa application on the morning of the 13th November. I subsequently withdrew the application on that day. However they issued me a visa based on that withdrawn application anyway, and the visa is dated 15th November 2019.

What do you think is happening here? Is the visa truly valid?

I applied for a 2-year visit visa together with my underaged kids on November 7. It suddenly occurred to me I might have made some mistakes/errors on my form on the 12th. I scouted the net for additional information and help regarding that error and based on what I got, I contacted UKVI that I intended to withdraw my application.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to reference the [history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/70240/tomolababy) behind this occurrence.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I just added additional information.

Comment: You didn't listen. Sad.

Comment: @greatone I know

Comment: VTC: unclear; as noted in comments, OP asked a [series of question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/70240/tomolababy), all of which were answered.... was *issued a visa* and then asks whether it's valid; no one here can possibly know that; OP has not returned since.